ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models.phi3'
When I try to run a LLM named ChatGLM3 in Aliyun, I run a python script to run a demo,but it comes out an error like this.enter image description here
How to solve it ?the LLM‘s github link is text，another py file named
streamlit run web_demo_streamlit.py is ok，but this py file python web_demo_gradio.py will end with this bug
solve the module not find problem in the picture

Check if the version number of your transformers is correct, I encountered the same problem as you. While fine-tuning chatglm, I tried updating my transformer version number, which solved the problem.
pip install transformer>=4.42.0
